# Unable to restore MS SQL Server backup into new created AWS RDS SQL Server database server instance

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, amazon-rds

I created a new SQL Server database in RDS using easy create option. I am using the Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio tool to restore the backup. But I get this error:

> An exception occurred while executing a Transact-SQL statement or batch. (Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo) The SELECT permission was denied on the object 'dm_os_enumerate_fixed_drives', database 'mssqlsystemresource', schema 'sys'. (.Net SqlClient Data Provider)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have completed all the pre-reqs:
To set up for native backup and restore on RDS SQL Server, you need three components;

1. An Amazon S3 bucket to store your backup files.
2. An AWS Identity and Access Management (IAM) role to access the bucket.
3. The SQLSERVER_BACKUP_RESTORE option added to an option group on your RDS DB instance.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/SQLServer.Procedural.Importing.html